# How to insert inside GWT an HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I am making a project with GWT, and I must insert some plain HTML code inside it. I have discovered that there is the HTML class that must be used like this:

```
HTML html=new HTML("<html> bla bla bla </html>");
```

The problem is that my HTML code has a link to a Javascript file. So my code looks more like this:

```
HTML html=new HTML("...<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>...");
```

But I don't know where the foo.js file must be located. The code now is in the method onModuleLoad.

Comment: The paths are relative to the `.html` file of your application. There is at least one `.html` file in your GWT application (entrypoint). Check that file and try to navigate to your js file from there. That's you path

Comment: I've just put foo.js in the same folder as welcomeGWT.html but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are checking the compiled files or the ones that you are developing in?

Comment: Your code is wrongly formatted. Use this: `HTML html=new HTML("...<script type='text/javascript' src='foo.js'></script>...");`. Notice the single quote use.

Comment: Ahs N in my real code I actually use double quotes. Alkis where are the compile files?

Comment: where is my war file? the one in dist? I've just tried but it's unuseful

Comment: Did you run the compiled version or the development/super user mode? You should try running the compiled version. When you do that, check the console log (F12 -> Console) for any errors